# How does one vertically center an Image inside parent div that's using css display:table?

Tags: html, css

I want to try and have the div that contains the image on the left to be centered vertically. I have tried numerous things but I keep running into issues.

`weekly-middle` is the container div to the div which is `left` which contains the image that I want centered.

The text is already centered.

```css
.weekly-middle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* height:100%;*/
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  /*clear: both;*/
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  /* padding-top: 56px; 
 padding-bottom: 56px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px
}

.right {
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="weekly-middle teal">
  <div class="left">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
    <p class="title">Problems Solved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution provided in comment below**

Refer to Joseph Marikle comment with link to JSFiddle.

Comment: Instead of: `display: table` use `display: inline-block;`, then the `vertial-align: middle` will work ;)

Comment: The question that this was marked as a duplicate of is not remotely similar to this question...

Comment: @mcv you're trying to use `display:table`, but in order to do that, you also need to have some element inside of the wrapper that has `display:table-cell`.  You have a table but no cells.  You also, shouldn't explicitly declare a height on the left column.  Lastly, don't float the columns.  Once you have `display:table-cell` on them, they'll line up accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/L8txsvLx/

Comment: Thank yo @JosephMarikle I have been searching and have not found a soultion

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox. It's a very powerfull CSS tool :

```
.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  /*    padding-top: 56px; 
    padding-bottom: 56px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: Nice but what if I remove the height?

Comment: Basically you can't align items vertically in a div that doesn't have specified height  !

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code

```
 <div class="left">
  <div class="display-table"> 
      <div class="display-table-cell">
<img width="50" height="50" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png" />
      </div>
 </div>
```

and for the css you can write:

```
.display-table{
     display: table;
     width:100%;
 }
 .display-table-cell{
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align:left;
      height: 100px;// your choose
 }
```

Comment: AS I write the code here please check out the spelling mistake in any. Thanks

Comment: I applied `display:table-cell` to the left and it work.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css, hope it helps:

```
.weekly-middle img {
margin-top:50%;
}
```

```css
.weekly-middle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* height:100%;*/
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  /*clear: both;*/
  
}
.weekly-middle img {
margin-top:50%;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  /* padding-top: 56px; 
 padding-bottom: 56px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px
}

.right {
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="weekly-middle teal">
  <div class="left">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
    <p class="title">Problems Solved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to just remove the 'left' and 'right' classes from the inner divs and it will work.

See if what you're looking for is below.

```css
.weekly-middle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* height:100%;*/
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  /*clear: both;*/
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  /* padding-top: 56px; 
 padding-bottom: 56px;*/
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 300px
}

.right {
  margin-left: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="weekly-middle teal">
  <div class="">
    <img width="50" height="50" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
    <p class="title">Problems Solved</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he wants it centered vertically..

Comment: Yeah the w is the left div besides the right div.